# Rename all files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, file, rename

I'm on a linux, and a download a lot of funny pictures. Unfortunately, I'm left with a bunch of duplicate names like `download (1)` and `image.jpeg`. I would like to change them all to something a bit more helpful.

Is there a way to (preferably using bash) to rename all files to sequential 4 digit numbers with leading zeroes?

Eg:

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet provided in the previous answer, is an elegant way of doing it but a typo or a shell incompatibility may cause it not to function properly.

please try the code below instead. It does the same thing but every shortcut has been explicitly written with debugging `echo` commands in the loop.

```
counter=1
cd /my/image/directory
for f in $(ls -1)
do
  new_filename=$(printf "%04d" ${counter})     
  echo "renaming ${f} ..to.. ${new_filename}"
  mv ${f} ${new_filename}
  (( counter=${counter}+1 ))
done
```

the screen output will be a little chatty. if you have too many files, you might want to add `| tee screen.out` to the end of the line with `done` command. So that you can go back and see what happened to which file recorded in the screen.out.

Comment: Don't use this! It will delete all files because counter isn't changing.

Answer (score 1):

I created [my own tool to do this](https://github.com/JoePShoulak/numberify). It also maintains file extensions, which I did not mention, but should probably be included. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

dir=$1
cd $dir
echo "Renaming all files in $dir."
COUNTER=1
for i in `ls -1`
do
  extension=${i##*.}
  mv "$i" "$COUNTER.$extension"
  echo "$i ==> $COUNTER.$extension"
  COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1 )
done
```

It does not (at the time of writing) include the leading zeroes, but it gets the job done.

Comment: and it fails miserably when it hits a filename that contains spaces. Don't parse the output of `ls`.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you don't care which file is renamed to what, it's easy :)

```
counter=1
for f in *; do
    mv "$f" "$( printf "%04d" $((counter++)) )"
done
```

Comment: So... there's one picture names 0001 now, and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

Trying to rename all files with suffix .bash to suffix .sh in a folder is easily done with

```
rename .bash .sh *.bash
```

Comment: This won't add a serial number as the question requests.